# Launch app on exit checkbox need to be checked by default

Tags: winforms, wix, wix3.5

We customized the WIX Installer  UI.

```
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi' xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">
......       
<CustomAction Id="StartAppOnExit" FileKey="AdminAppExe" ExeCommand="" Execute="immediate" Impersonate="yes" Return="asyncNoWait" />
        <Property Id="LAUNCHAPPONEXIT" Value="1"/>

<Control Id="LAUNCHAPPONEXIT" Type="CheckBox" X="10" Y="243" Width="170" Height="17" Property="StartAppOnExit" Hidden="yes" CheckBoxValue="1" Text=" Launch App?">
              <Condition Action="show">NOT Installed</Condition>
</Control>
.....
</Wix>
```

But the Checkbox to Launch app is not enabled by default? Pls let me know what i am doing wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the property `LAUNCHAPPONEXIT`, presumably to check the box by default. However the Control is using a different property - `StartAppOnExit`.

You'll need to set the value of the property that the checkbox is using, or change the checkbox to use the property that you are setting.